VLCJ doesnt output file
// VLC media options for saving to MP3 file
String outputFilePath = "C:\\Users\\FuLong\\Desktop\\output.mp3";
String[] mediaOptions = {
    "--sout", "#transcode{acodec=mp3,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=raw,dst=" + outputFilePath + "}",
    "--no-sout-display"
};

Almost everything and it doesnt work

"doesn't work" is not actionable. What's the exit status? What logs are written to stderr? Is the behavior the same if you use a relative path and change the working directory so you can just set output.mp3 as the name? (If that makes a difference, it implies that there might be some quoting or escaping needed for the backslashes to be permitted).
